# Magit cannot commit. emacsclient on PATH. Pop! OS

Tags: magit, emacsclient

magit-status sees the repo just fine, and I can even push to Github, or make a branch. I can also commit through the git cli no problem.

However, before I can even write my commit message on magit I get the following error:

```
 1 git … commit --
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Not inside Git repository
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/emacsclient.emacs --socket-name=/run/user/1000/emacs/server39157'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I read *(with-editor)Configuring With-Editor* on magit's manual, but I don't believe my installation of Emacs is abnormal. I installed it through the usual `sudo apt install emacs`. Furthermore, both *emacsclient* and *emacsclient.emacs* **are** located on `/usr/bin`. I tried customizing `with-editor-emacsclient-executable` to just `usr/bin/emacsclient` (no .emacs), to no avail.

There's a couple of lines to note in the output of `with-editor-debug`. For brevity, I've added the entire output to this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/SLthzKZV).

```
  server-auth-dir: ~/.emacs.d/server/
    WARNING: not an accessible directory
```

When I checked, the *server* sub-directory didn't exist. I tried creating it, but still, no success.

I'd be grateful if someone could give me directions on this. Committing through cli is getting tiresome .

My installation's versions is:

```
Magit 20221008.1927 [>= 3.3.0-git], Git 2.34.1, Emacs 27.1, gnu/linux
```

Cheers!

Comment: Can you open an existing file with `emacsclient <somefile>`? How about a non-existent file, writing something into it and saving it? If those succeed, then it's probably a magit problem; otherwise it's an emacsclient one.

Comment: @NickD Just tried that. Seems to work just fine, both opening an existing file, and creating/saving another. I did have to start the server from emacs, I'm assuming that's standard procedure. I also tried committing again, but previously starting the server, same thing. Looks like a magit thing still.

Comment: I found one github issue about this.  Does any of this sound familiar to you?  https://github.com/magit/with-editor/issues/69

Comment: That `*ERROR*: Not inside Git repository` is making me curious too.  People with similar issues solved that by adding paths to `exec-path`.  In those cases, emacs couldn't find the git executable.  I don't know if that's your problem, but it's worth verifying that emacs can find git.

Comment: @g-gundam Similar symptoms, but my error message doesn't seem external to magit. As suggested in that issue, I searched for the error on the installed packages. Turns out, it's from `magit-git.el`. In it, one of the four functions that raise the same error is `magit-inside-gitdir-p`. And sure enough, if I run the commented command `git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir` in the working directory, it returns _false_. I don't know yet what this means, but I'm starting to think there's a bad config somewhere.

Comment: Concerning _exec-path_, emacs can find the git executable no problem. Git is also in PATH, and `exec-path` is set to it's location.